# Save a value in select HTML after validation

Tags: php, html

I would like to save a selection in 'select' but it doesn't work. When you type on submit button, the selection don't display the old value in a 'select'.

Here the code of the function :

```
function afficher_cours($cxn) {
$requete="SELECT ID_COURS, SIGLE FROM COURS ORDER BY SIGLE";
$res = mysqli_query($cxn, $requete);
echo '<select name = "cours">';
while($ligne = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){ 
    if(isset($_POST[$cours]) AND ($_POST[$cours] == $ligne)) {
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $selected='';
    }
echo "<option value = $ligne[0] $selected > $ligne[1] </option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

}

And here the code of the script :

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Classe </td>
        <td> 
            <?php afficher_classe() ?>
        </td>
        <td> Cours </td>
        <td> <?php afficher_cours($cxn) ?> </td>
        <td> Numéro du test  </td>
        <td> <?php selection_noTest(0, 5, 'noTest'); ?> </td>
        <td>
            <input type="SUBMIT" name="afficher" value="Afficher"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
if(isset($_POST['afficher'])) {
        $cours = $_POST['cours'];
        $classe = $_POST['classe'];
        $noTest = $_POST['noTest'];
        $annee = ANNEE;
        $_SESSION['cours'] = $cours;
        $_SESSION['noTest'] = $noTest;
        $requete = "SELECT NBTESTS, EXAMEN FROM COURS WHERE ID_COURS = $cours";
        $res = mysqli_query($cxn, $requete);
        echo (mysqli_error ($cxn));
        $ligne = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
        $_SESSION['nbTests'] = $ligne['NBTESTS'];
        $_SESSION['examen'] = $ligne['EXAMEN'];
        if (($noTest > $ligne['NBTESTS']) OR (($noTest == 0) AND ($ligne['EXAMEN'] == 'non'))) {
            echo 'Le numéro du test est incorrect pour ce cours. <br/>';}
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: In a function, I tried to replace '$ligne' in '$ligne['ID_ELEVE']' but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

your function seems to be working, though I've done some minor changes.. please check it..

```
function afficher_cours($cxn) {
   $requete="SELECT ID_COURS, SIGLE FROM COURS ORDER BY SIGLE";
   $res = mysqli_query($cxn, $requete);
   echo '<select name = "cours">';
   while($ligne = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){ 
      if(isset($_POST['cours']) AND ($_POST['cours'] == $ligne[0])) { //Changed $ligne to $ligne[0] and $_POST['cours'] instead of $_POST[$cours]
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
      } else {
        $selected='';
      }
      echo "<option value = '".$ligne[0]."' ".$selected." > ".$ligne[1]."</option>"; // modified this line too
   }
   echo '</select>';
}
```

you're fetching `ID_COURS, SIGLE` then you can not access `$ligne['ID_ELEVE']`, so it is possible that it does not work.

I've doubt, Do you get `<select>` dropdown with correct values?

**Edit:**
There should be `$_POST['cours']` instead of `$_POST[$cours]`, as `$curs` is not defined in function!! that will give you an error "Undefined variable: cours"

Comment: Values is correct and your modification doesn't work too

Comment: @Sab25, I've edited my answer. This time it is solution for you, please check it and let me know..